# Real time stock volatility

Tags: volatility

Is there any need for real time weighted volatility on a tick by tick basis for equities?

If you had that access to that, what could you do with it?

Comment: Are you asking because you're offering a product in this space?

Comment: no, I'm playing around with parellel GPU programming. Looking for a something worthwhile to do. Calculating realtime option smiles might be better but I want to concentrate more on the architecture first... I'm open to publishing the code once I got it complete, so is it of any interest to anyone?

Comment: I do not believe that GPU is of any help for HFT-related computation, too many time is lost in the memory bus.

Comment: I already answered to a very similar question about [computing high-frequency volatility](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-to-calculate-historical-intraday-volatility/3264#3264)