# What good papers of short term (<30 seconds) volatility estimation

Tags: volatility, high-frequency, estimation, market-microstructure, high-frequency-estimators

I am looking for good papers of short term (<30 sec) volatility estimation AND short term volatility forecasting.
Do you have something in mind ?

Comment: this question is already answered here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-to-calculate-historical-intraday-volatility/ (see my answer)

Answer (score 7):

Very interesting question. I am not an expert on the subject, however, I was able to find a collection of papers on the subject that should get you started.

Here is a good and very informative paper that walks you through several tick by tick volatility estimators that seek to reduce the volatility imposed by market micro-structure:

[Efficient estimation of volatility using high frequency data
G Zumbach, F Corsi, A Trapletti](https://www.olseninvest.com/customer/pdf/paper/020221-efficientVolEstimator.pdf)

Here is one of the first papers on the subject:

[High-frequency data and volatility in foreign-exchange rates
B Zhou - Journal of Business & Economic Statistics, 1996](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~get/browse/courses/201/spr11/DOWNLOADS/MicroStructure/Zhou-JBES-1996.pdf)

Analysis of market micro-structure noise here:

[Realized variance and market microstructure noise
PR Hansen, A Lunde - Journal of Business & Economic Statistics, 2006](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~get/browse/courses/201/spr10/DOWNLOADS/MicroStructureNoise/Hansen-Lunde-JBES-2006+COMMENTS/s1.pdf)

Another article proposing sub-sampling techniques:
[A tale of two time scales
L Zhang, PA Mykland, 2005](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1164&context=statistics)

Generally, there is a wealth of papers on the subject of short term volatility estimation. You can take a [look at this list](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=5923881265989503428&as_sdt=20000005&sciodt=0,21&hl=en) of papers citing Zhou's original paper to find relevant research.

Short term volatility forecasting is another very interesting subject. If you get good volatility estimates, you should be able to use standard techniques for forecasting.

Here is one paper:

[Forecasting volatility using tick by tick data, RF Engle, Z Sun - 2005](http://irps.ucsd.edu/assets/007/5581.pdf)